# Grails context.GrailsContextLoader Error initializing the application: Method on class [] was used outside of a Grails application

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

My grails version: 2.3.4

Hibernate plugin: runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.6"

This is the line in Bootstrap.groovy that generates error:

> def adminRole = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save(flush: true)

Actually any save operation in any class (controller, Bootstrap.groovy) results in this error.

But when I get domain classes that are created in another computer, that works fine,no error.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Full stacktrace:

```
ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader Error initializing the application: Method on class [etezia.Role] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method on class [etezia.Role] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.
    at BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:9)
    at grails.util.Environment.evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock(Environment.java:308)
    at grails.util.Environment.executeForEnvironment(Environment.java:301)
    at grails.util.Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment(Environment.java:277)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: can you please provide the full stacktrace of the exception

Comment: i added full stacktrace of the exception,thanks.

Comment: try def adminRole = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save(failOnError: true)

Comment: are you using Maven to run your Grails application?

Comment: I rechecked,and see that I am using Maven.

Comment: try def adminRole = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save(failOnError: true)
results in same exception

Comment: it might be related to the issue reported [here](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Blocking-issue-with-run-app-using-grails-maven-plugin-in-dev-environment-v-2-3-1-td4651499.html). Upgrading to the latest Grails Maven plugin may help

Comment: In BuildConfig.groovy there is line related to maven, but there is no plugin version info: grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy

Comment: and there is no maven plugin listed in my plugins, can I stil upgrade maven?

Comment: The issue which I referred to is relevant if you run the application using the [Grails Maven plugin](https://github.com/grails/grails-maven). From the info you provided, I don't think this is the case.